# componentDidMount is not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm calling  ajax request `this.props.getPostListData(this.props.lang)` and got error. Then I've found out that it's componentDidMount to blame.
My `componentDidMount` is not called in `News.jsx` component and when I replace it to `componentWillMount` - the ajax request is called.
I use **Redux**, and **React Router v4**

#### News.jsx

```
class News extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.getPostListData(this.props.lang);
  }

  props: {
    urlPrefix: string,
    lang: string,
    postList: PostListData,
    getPostListData: Function
  };

  render() {
    const { postList, urlPrefix } = this.props;
    return (
      <section className={'news'}>
        ...
        <NewsCards posts={postList} urlPrefix={urlPrefix} />
      </section>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const urlPrefix = getPrefix(state.locale);
  const postList = state.postlistData ? state.postlistData : [];
  const lang = getLang(state.locale);
  return { postList, lang, urlPrefix };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Function) => ({
  getPostListData(locale) {
    dispatch(getPostList(locale));
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(News);
```

#### Routes.jsx

```
const Routes = ({ urlPrefix }: { urlPrefix: string }) => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="app">
      <Route render={props => <Header urlPrefix={urlPrefix} {...props} />} />
      <Switch>
        <RootRouter exact
          path={'/:lang(en|ru)?'} urlPrefix={urlPrefix} component={Landing} />
        <Route exact path={'/:lang(en|ru)?/news'} component={News} />
        <Route component={FourOhFour} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ urlPrefix: getPrefix(state.locale) });    
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Routes);
```

Comment: can you also include `getPostList`, one used in `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: @przemo_li  getPostList works fine with componentWillMount, besides if I add console.log before getPostList it's not called either in ..DidMount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I replace  `NewsCards`  component:

```
<NewsCards posts={postList} urlPrefix={urlPrefix} />
```

to

```
<pre><code>{JSON.stringify(postList)}</code></pre>
```

everything's working fine. So the problem is in  ***NewsCards*** component. I need to check it more precisely.